# what is best Mysql query string field to grouped jsonarray?

Tags: mysql

I develop tag database structure

### 3 table

### tags

> id, name

- 79    A-1
- 80    A-2
- 81    A-3
- 82    A-4
- 83    A-5

### tagmap

> id,    content_id,  tag_id

- 39    1617    79
- 40    1617    80
- 41    1617    81
- 42    1617    82
- 43    1617    83

### content

> content_id

- 1617

> Blockquote

```
select cast(concat('[',group_concat( json_quote(t.name) ),']') as json)  
  from contents a  
       left join tagmap m on a.content_id = m.content_id
       inner join tags t on m.tag_id = t.id
 where a.content_id = 1617;
```

result => ["A-1", "A-2", "A-3", "A-4", "A-5"]

correct result

But Is there are better way then this?

Comment: Better or not is an opinion. But i'd probably just fetch the related tags and convert them to JSON in application language.

Comment: @PaulSpiegel Thanks!